# Download ZIP file from URL with .jsp (Python)

Tags: python, python-requests, zip

I am trying to download a ZIP file from a URL that contains .jsp in it (http://www.b3.com.br/lumis/portal/file/fileDownload.jsp?fileId=8AA8D0CD770C93F201770DC559CC3E5E).

When I click the link it automatically downloads it.

Also, the ZIP file contains only a .txt.

Comment: What is the problem to be solved? If it is simply downloading the file, refer to this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to go to that site it redirects me somewhere else. Try the link http://www.b3.com.br/lumis/portal/file/fileDownload.jsp
I am getting the page not found